# Multiple files as input on Amazon Elastic MapReduce

Tags: java, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run a job on Elastic MapReduce (EMR) with a custom jar. I'm trying to process about a 1000 files in a single directory. When I submit my job with the parameter `s3n://bucketname/compressed/*.xml.gz`, I get a "matched 0 files" error. If I pass just the absolute path to a file (e.g. `s3n://bucketname/compressed/00001.xml.gz`), it runs fine, but only one file gets processed. I tried using the name of the directory (`s3n://bucketname/compressed/`), hoping that the files within will be processed, but that just passes the directory to the job.

At the same time, I have a smaller local hadoop installation. In that, when I pass my job with wildcards (`/path/to/dir/on/hdfs/*.xml.gz`), it works fine and all 1000 files are listed correctly.

How do I get EMR to list all my files?

Comment: Alternately, how do I list the files within a directory in s3 from the code? I can then generate the paths from those files.

Comment: It works now! There was an empty file called `compressed` in the same bucket. As soon as I deleted the empty file, the program started working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how EMR lists all the files, but here's a piece of code which works for me:

```
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(args[0]), job.getConfiguration());
        FileStatus[] files = fs.listStatus(new Path(args[0]));
        for(FileStatus sfs:files){
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, sfs.getPath());
        }
```

It will list all the files which are in the input directory, and you can do to those anything that you will

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem was fixed later. There was an empty file called compressed in the same bucket. As soon as I deleted the empty file, the program started working.